# How to use multiple replace in r without changing the original dataset?

Tags: r, replace

I have a dataset where I need to replace, for one of the variables, all the value above the .99 percentile and below 0, with a NA. 
Since I need to plot multiple variables, I am trying to create a template where I can just imput the variables i need to plot and then have it save w/o changing the original dataset since I need to do different kind of graph.

How do I nest two replace function tho?

```
na.omit(replace(data$Sodio, which(data$Sodio <0), NA)))
```

this is the first one I used, but I also need to replace the number above this number

```
quantile(data$Sodio, probs=c(0.99), na.rm=TRUE)
```

So i'd need something like

```
na.omit(replace(data$Sodio, which(data$Sodio>quantile(data$Sodio, probs=c(0.99), na.rm=TRUE), NA)))
```

Is it possible to just write one string and achieve both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine the two conditions with OR (`|`)

```
new_data <- transform(data, Sodio = replace(Sodio, 
             Sodio > quantile(Sodio, probs=0.99, na.rm=TRUE) | Sodio < 0, NA))
```